# Android Individual Tab Colors

Tags: android, colors, tabs, tabwidget

I have created four tabs but want each tab to be a different block color - should this be done in the xml or java file? I'm assuming java because I only have one xml file for the whole tab widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to customise the individual tabs
try using something like

```
TabWidget tabWidget = getTabWidget();
for(int i = 0; i < tabWidget.getChildCount(); i++) {
RelativeLayout tabLayout = (RelativeLayout) tabWidget.getChildAt(i);
tabLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(someimage);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I have white logo images ready for each tab but want a background colour for each. Or is there any way I can make the image stretch over the entire tab to get this effect? Thanks! :)

Comment: i think tabLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(someimage); will set the image . I mean stretch the image (but not sure)

Comment: or have a look a look at http://ondrejcermak.info/programovani/custom-tabs-in-android-tutorial/comment-page-1/

Comment: if this helped you try to please post a sample code that helped to solve your problem so that even others can use.